# Converting API data in React-Redux: Action or Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have a weather app that the api data comes in different formats so I made up an object of methods the I can convert that data to imperial format and time from UTC to GMT.

Right now I have those methods being called on the data in my reducer.

Question: Is that "okay" or should that conversions be done in the corresponding action prior to the payload being delivered to the reducer? Just curious what the best practice for something like this is.

FYI: I'm using `axios` as my promise based HTTP client and `redux-promise-middleware`, `redux-lodger`, & `redux-promise` as my middleware in the store.

Action Creator:

```
export const fetchCurrentWeather = (city) => {
const url = `${CURRENT_ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   axios.get(url)
     .then(res => resolve(res.data))
     .catch(err => reject(err));

});
return {
  type: FETCH_CURRENT_WEATHER,
  payload: promise
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```
export default(state = initialState, action) => {
const data = action.payload;
switch (action.type) {
    case `${FETCH_CURRENT_WEATHER}_PENDING`:
        return {};
    case `${FETCH_CURRENT_WEATHER}_FULFILLED`:
    const prefix = 'wi wi-owm-';
    const code = data.weather[0].id;
    const icon = prefix + code;
        return {
            ...state,
            weatherData: {
              humidity: data.main.humidity,
              icon,
              name: data.name,
              pressure: unitConverter.toInchesHG(data.main.pressure),
              sunrise: unitConverter.toGMT(data.sys.sunrise),
              sunset: unitConverter.toGMT(data.sys.sunset),
              temp: unitConverter.toFarenheit(data.main.temp),
              winddir: unitConverter.toCardinal(data.wind.deg),
              windspd: unitConverter.toMPH(data.wind.speed)
            },
            isFetched: true
        };
    case `${FETCH_CURRENT_WEATHER}_REJECTED`:
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetched: true,
            err: data
        };
    default:
        return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have three locations where you could usefully process your raw data:

- **A component's `render()` function**

  This is not normally a good idea as it would mean the data is processed each time the component is rendered. If you use a package like [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) you can mitigate the performance issues through caching, but even then the actual code e.g.  *sorting* or *filtering* should be kept in the `mapStateToProps()`.
- **In the reducer**

  A better case can be made for the processing data in the reducer but I would argue that for reasons of clarity, and separation of concerns, this is still not the best place. The reducer's job is pretty clear - to concede the action and merge the previous state with the action results, anything only else serves to blur the lines of responsibility and testability.
- **An action thunk**

  In my opinion, an action thunk  is the correct location for once-only data transformations such as the normalisation / conversion of imported raw data. Not only is it typically a clear action sub-task (e.g. get weather data -> convert celsius to fahrenheit) but it also has the added advantage of not storing useless data, even if temporarily, in state.

  To quote Dan Abramov:

  > ... action objects [are] minimal representations of what happened and
  >   state objects [are] minimal representations of what’s necessary for
  >   rendering right now.

**Final Note - Selectors**

Although I said above that the component is not a good place to perform raw-data transformations, in fact I think there is an argument to be made for storing the *raw-data* in redux-state and using a package like [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) to present the normalised or computed values via `selectors` as required.

One way to achieve this would be to have a `selector` function that performs the data normalisation on a defined portion of the raw-data. Using the [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) package, this conversion would be cached and so only performed once. It would have the advantage of *lazy-converting* the data only as required.

Comment: thanks! I was toying with the idea of moving the conversions to the action because it just seemed like I'm still performing and `action` on the data and the reducer is not really suppose to be doing that. I will checkout the `reselect` package. Thanks again!